# Dealing with inaccessible exception types

Tags: java, exception

I'm working with a third-party library that has some very specific exception types for different scenarios. I'd like to use them like this (a somewhat simplified version):

```
try
{...}
catch (IllegalFooOperationException e)
{
    //handle an illegal foo
}
catch (InvalidBarValueException e)
{
    //handles very differently from the illegal foo.
}
```

Unfortunately, `IllegalFooOperationException` and `InvalidBarValueException` are *not* public classes: they are package-scoped. They inherit from a much more generic public `GenericThirdPartyAPIException` class.

Right now, this sort-of works:

```
catch (GenericThirdPartyAPIException e)
{
    String rootExceptionTypeName = e.getClass().getName();
    if (rootExceptionTypeName.equals("someAPI.IllegalFooOperationException"))
    {
        //handle illegal foo
    }
    else if (rootExceptionTypeName.equals("someAPI.InvalidBarValueException"))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

But this just doesn't feel right. One potential problem is that if the packages or class names change in the future in this library, this code won't be able to find the right exception class at runtime. I don't like relying on figuring out an object's class at runtime if I don't have to.

I also thought about trying to parse the exception message directly, but there some of the exceptions I'm interested in (not all are shown here) *might* have the same message, but be of a different type.

Is there a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: "But this just doesn't feel right" - well that's what happens when a library designer makes bad choices. Can you ask the library author to make the exceptions public?

Comment: You cannot use `instanceof` as exception types are package protected.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I could certainly ask, but regardless of whether or not they reply or are even willing to make changes, I still need to deploy *my* code.

Answer (score 2):

In the initialization you could execute a method that for sure throws **IllegalFooOperationException** and save the class of the exception in a variable.
Do the same thing for the other exceptions, and you shoud have all the exception classes.

I know that this is not a good practice (as the package protected exceptions are are as well) but you will be able to find the right exception class at runtime.

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting idea!